# Server-Side Database in GWT project

Tags: java, database, gwt

I am developping a project in GWT and I need to use a databse.
I already found some documentations about databases link with GWT but I am not really satisfied by what I have found..

The principle is the following :
Users entry some input on the website that has to saved into a quite simple format on the server (a digit and a string).

What is, for you, the best option to use ?

Comment: What is the best option for what? What kind of database, client/server communication? Be more specific what you want to know.

Comment: I don't have favourite option for the kind of database. I have to store object that are composed of one digit and a string. Then, it can be store in a text file, in a sql database, in a persistence way (hibernate) .. I just don't know which is the easiest to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here:

http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html

This describes the way how to call the server. Once the data is available on the server, it is quite easy to do a database call.